# declaring multiple variables in javascript based on the quantity of children

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, mutation-observers

Im pretty new to programming and im trying to develop a chrome extension. The website that im trying to manipulate has a `div` element and within this `div` are multiple `div`s and the number of these `div`s varies depending on the scale of the first `div` and the scale is draggable by the user. My problem is that, I need to declare each of these variables and have a mutation observer observe them for changes. So a user might have 8 `div` in the draggable window and another user might have 12 `div` in there so I want to have 8 or 12 mutation observers respectively.  Below is my code:

```
span1 = document.getElementsByClassName("text right")[0];



const observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
        var spantext = span1.textContent;
        var spandiv = span1.parentNode;
        
        
        if (mutation.addedNodes) {
            if (spantext > avg) {
                spandiv.style.backgroundColor = "#E8E8E8"
                spandiv.style.color = "black";
                spandiv.style.opacity = "0.7";
            }
            if (spantext < avg) {
                spandiv.style.backgroundColor = "black";
                spandiv.style.color = "white";
                spandiv.style.opacity = "1";
            }
        }
    })
});
const options = {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true,
    attributes: true,
    characterData: true
};
observer.observe(span1, options);
span2 = document.getElementsByClassName("text right")[1];
const observer2 = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
        var spantext = span2.textContent;
        var spandiv = span2.parentNode;
        
        if (mutation.addedNodes) {
            if (spantext > avg) {
                spandiv.style.backgroundColor = "#E8E8E8"
                spandiv.style.color = "black";
                spandiv.style.opacity = "0.7";
                
            }
            if (spantext < avg) {
                spandiv.style.backgroundColor = "black";
                spandiv.style.color = "white";
                spandiv.style.opacity = "1";
                
            }
        }
    })
});
observer2.observe(span2, options);
```

As you can see I have made 2 mutation observers and they are observing two `div`s but this is practical only when the user has 2 of the `div`s in their draggable window.
I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Loop over all the DIVs with `forEach()` and add a mutation observer for each of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a loop to add the mutation observer to all the DIVs.

```js
document.querySelector(".text.right").forEach(span => {
  const observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
      var spantext = span.textContent;
      var spandiv = span.parentNode;

      if (mutation.addedNodes) {
        if (spantext > avg) {
          spandiv.style.backgroundColor = "#E8E8E8"
          spandiv.style.color = "black";
          spandiv.style.opacity = "0.7";
        }
        if (spantext < avg) {
          spandiv.style.backgroundColor = "black";
          spandiv.style.color = "white";
          spandiv.style.opacity = "1";
        }
      }
    })
  });
  const options = {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true,
    attributes: true,
    characterData: true
  };
  observer.observe(span, options);
});
```